# React Context API Extract value from the object containing Provider/Consumer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

In the below codesandbox example, I am using a Context API object (via a library 'react-singleton-context')
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/shared-context-r4f4tw?file=%2Fsrc%2FMenu.js%3A7%2C39

Now, in the Menu.js, where I am doing
`console.log(useSharedDataContext())`;

I can see following object with Consumer/Provider printed as below;

[image]

How can I extract the actual value i.e. "sharedData" from this object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the value of a context, use the `useContext` hook:

```
const Menu = () => {
  const value = useContext(useSharedDataContext());
}
```

Ps, `useSharedDataContext` is not calling any hooks, so i would recommend you don't name it using the hook convention. Perhaps `getSharedDataContext()`.

```
export const getSharedDataContext = () => getContext(SharedDataContext))
// ... used like:
const value = useContext(getSharedDataContext());
```

Or you could bake the call to `useContext` into it, and then it *does* deserve the hook naming.

```
export const useSharedDataContext = () => useContext(getContext(SharedDataContext));
// ... used like:
const value = useSharedDataContext()
```